# Probability of a path

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Let's say I have quantum particle and I wanted to find the probability that this particle goes through a chosen path. Is this practically possible?

Comment: Yes, but the probability of any one path is zero. You could specify a certain (elongated) volume in space and then use a path integral to evaluate the volume probability with a path integral. I think that's a well enough defined concept and it will lead to finite results, even though the practical calculation is not for the faint of heart. See e.g. http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/pathintegral.pdf for an introduction. See also http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0004090.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You express yourself not correctly from the point of view of the quantum mechanics. A particle doesn't "go through a chosen path". It's correct to say that a quantum particle "can be found on some path".

To give you an example, assume a beam splitter, $BS$, a detector $A$ oriented toward the lower face of the $BS$ and a detector $B$ oriented toward the upper face of the $BS$. Assume that a quantum particle impinges on the $BS$. We say that the particle may be reflected by the $BS$, or transmitted. But that is not rigorous. If the particle is detected at some time $t$ by the detector $A$, nothing ensures that if it were detected at a time $t - dt$ it would have been detected also by the detector $A$. We cannot say about a quantum particle that it has a **trajectory**.

A trajectory is a continuous track in the space, characterized at any time $t$ by a position $\vec r(t)$ and a velocity $\vec v(t)$.

Now, to your question within the above specifications, if you know the wave-function $\psi (\vec r, t)$, you can calculate at any time $t$ the probability to find the particle at the position $\vec r$.

Comment: He can do a path integral. It won't give him anything useful, but it can be calculated.